# Pagination with express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am doing pagination with mongoose & express and this is the code

```
 const page = req.query.page || 1;
 const limit = 15;
 const docs = await Model.find({
    visibility: true,  
    $or: [{expires: {$gt: new Date().getTime()}}, {expires: null}]
 })
 .skip((page * limit) - limit)
 .limit(limit);
```

this causes error (no message it logs Network error only) but i know the cause of problem is this piece of code because when I delete it, it starts working. what is problem?

**EDIT**

i changed this code to

```
Model.find({
    visibility: true,  
    $or: [{expires: {$gt: new Date().getTime()}}, {expires: null}]
})
.skip(page * limit - limit)
.limit(15)
.exec((err,docs)=>{
    if(err){
       //handle err
    }
    res.status(200).send({
         docs
    })
})
```

and it started working. it sounds good but i need to know why didn't it work with await syntax

Comment: Did you put a try catch or .catch to see?

Comment: i have try catch inside `router.get()` but it does not send anything, only Network error  while disconnecting server (i use react for client)

Comment: How many records in the collection and what it is the value of limit here

Comment: 1 document and limit is 15

Comment: 1 document with this filter

Comment: Then give a [mcve] *of that*.